# Problems with Startup

Tags: startup

I'm new to ubuntu and I have been having a problem. I installed Ubuntu 13.10 via flash drive and whenever I try to start up my computer it gives me the error "/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx does not exist, dropping to shell.
Then if i type "exit" in the shell it will go to the ubuntu loading screen and start up just fine. Any idea what is causing this problem?

Comment: This may be problem in `/etc/fstab`. Could you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/439728/edit) your question and add this file?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, your flash drive need to be unplugged, or just change the boot priority to let the hard drive have the highest priority if you don't want to remove the USB Drive.

So try unplugging the USB Drive and turn on the computer and see.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by editing the menu entry's in boot menu .i.e grub.

```
Enter into your grub menu pressing 'e' at boot time.
Remove the search line by pressing 'Del'
Go to your Linux line and change root=UUID= to root=/dev/sda# your root partition.
```

Done..!
and you can also check your  `fstab` file and fix it.